# Best time to go in Brittany to avoid both school holidays and hurricanes?

Tags: weather-and-climate, photography, school-holidays, brittany

My wife and myself want to go for a photo-shooting on the beaches of Saint-Malo, France, but not especially in the summer. We want it to happen when there aren't many people there, so we want to avoid French holidays (which usually last one month because of the shifted holidays accross the country).

Also every year, we hear about those hurricanes and gigantic waves on the Atlantic shores of France. We definitely want to avoid that extreme weather.

So what are the times of the year to travel to Brittany where there are both no school holidays and no hurricanes?

Comment: Hurricanes? France? Every year? I think you're mistaken. Hurricanes/cyclones are very rare there....

Comment: Evidence of the lack of proper hurricanes/cyclones in Europe as a whole: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_cyclone_effects_in_Europe

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica I don't know if "hurricane" or "cyclone" is the appropriate word, but I know that every year, the west coast is hit by gigantic waves for months. I just don't remember the time of the year where that happens. That's what we want to avoid.

Comment: St Malo isn't on the west coast...

Answer (score 3):

I used to travel to Brittany every summer, and before having a child in school we'd usually go in *late June or early July*. You normally get summer weather, but avoid the hordes of children. It's a popular destination for British families so it's worth avoiding the British school holidays as well, and even the Dutch ones. The downsides are: the sea temperatures are still a little low, (not an issue if you're not going in the water); not everything is open.

Just after the school holidays, in *September*, it's also quiet (maybe not the first week). Again some places are closed, such as restaurants taking a holiday, but the sea will be warmer. I've had good weather then too, but probably more rain. As you get into autumn the chance of rain increases, though the storms you worry about are fairly rare all year round (and dramatic if you find the right cliff-top spot to watch them).